# How to NOT load JQM CSS in one of the HTML pages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQM/JQ/JS/HTML5/CSS/etc./etc. to make an app, that later on will be packed with phonegap.

I have the index.html where I load everything I need. Then, in that page I link to page1.html, and then, I have another page, page2.html that I link to in page1.html

The page2.html is basically a photoswipe gallery. What I want to do is to NOT load the JQM css on that page; simply beucase it will make everything ugly and weird.

How can I tell JQM css not to load only on that page? I know I can NOT include it in the header, but for that I need to refresh the page to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for you answer. I'm not familiar with JQ and JQM, I'm only learning so far.

After I've submitted this question, I kept looking around and finally found this: http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling/

I used  data-role="none" on all the elements that I didn't want to style and it worked as I hoped and wanted to.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On your link to page2, use `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` to avoid loading it into the DOM of the index page.

DOC: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false") have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external" should be used when linking to another site or domain, while data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your domain from being loaded via Ajax.